# Get quadrant value after reflecting points across x axis

Tags: c++, math, graph

I have a number of points on a 2D graph, and I am concerned with they quadrant they lie in than the actual coordinates itself. I have a function ReflectX() which performs "Reflecting along X-axis" on a subset and returns the updated quadrant in which the points now lie.
So, points originally in quadrant 1 will now lie in 4 and vice-versa; similarly for quadrant 2 and 3.
Instead of using 4 if-else statements, I want to use just 2, for optimising. Can that be done? Any suggestions for other kind of optimisation is also welcome. What I have done so far (which isnt much):

```
int ReflectX(int q[], int x, int y){//x & y provide the range boundaries
    int i;
    for(i=x-1; i<y; i++){
        if(q[i]==1 || q[i]==4) q[i]=(q[i]+3)%6;
        else //change 2 into 3 and 3 into 2
    }
}
```

EDIT: I had not posted about ReflectY() because I could do it with one if-else condition. However, based on [Adam Rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9530/adam-rosenfield) 's answer I decided to optimise this function with a one-liner formula and got:

```
q[i] = (q[i] - pow(-1, q[i]%2));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a much simpler answer by just looking at the table of all possible inputs and outputs:

```
Initial quadrant   Reflected quadrant
1                  4
2                  3
3                  2
4                  1
```

So, just do this:

```
q[i] = 5 - q[i];
```